# Div cover parent div with min-height

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and child div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
        Foo Bar!
    </div>
</div>
```

The `wrapper` div can vary in height, depending on the content, but it has a `min-height: 50vh`. Now I want the child div to cover the entire parent div, but `height: 100%` does not work.

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9yod7s0/8/). The goal is to cover the entire grey area in blue. How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flexbox` may help.

Add these code to the `.wrapper`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
```

Remove `height` and add `width` to the child.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    Foo Bar!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply and **easiest** way is to use `display: flex` and `width: 100%` on the `.child`.

> **Flex** is very `responsive` on all modern browsers. You can read more about [flex box here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Demo**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    Foo Bar!
  </div>
</div>
```